# while loop returning the second to last value

Tags: python-3.x

So I understand the logic but don't know how to get it to do what I want. I feel it's super simple but... I need it to record the last valid answer and store it into I but it returns the second to last value since the while loop doesn't iterate again. Relevant code and pictures are attached. Thank you all for any help.

```
INVALID_CHARACTERS = r"!#$%&'()*+,-.:;<=>?@[]^_`{|}~\/" + '"'
INVALID_NUMBERS = "1234567890"
INVALID_LETTERS = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

def letter_validity_check(i, msg):
    """Function checks entered answers against a list of invalid characters and invalid numbers"""

    while len(i) == 0 or any(c in INVALID_CHARACTERS for c in i) or any(c in INVALID_NUMBERS for c in i):
        i = input("First name can not be blank, contain special characters, or numbers. Try again. \n" + msg)

    while len(i) != 0 and any(c not in INVALID_CHARACTERS for c in i) and any(c not in INVALID_NUMBERS for c in i) and any(c in INVALID_LETTERS for c in i):
        print (i)
        return i

while len(FIRST_NAME) == 0:
    MESSAGE =  "What is your first name?: "
    FIRST_NAME = input(MESSAGE)
    letter_validity_check(FIRST_NAME, MESSAGE)
    print(FIRST_NAME)
    exit_checker(FIRST_NAME)
```

[While loop and the logic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZEJn.png)

Comment: Your `return I` statement is indented, so is within the while loop and will execute on the first iteration of the loop. Is that what you intended?

Comment: @jarmod I don't think so? I understand what you are saying but it still returns the older input. Sorry the logic has been destroying me as of lately

Comment: Why do you even have the second while loop within `letter_validity_check`? What is its purpose?

Comment: @jarmod It's supposed to give a validation message. I suppose I could do an else or something. Still don't know how to get the most recent value

Comment: What is "the most recent value"? Perhaps you could enhance your post by showing us your input and then explaining what output you actually see as well as what output you expected to see.

Comment: @jarmod Please see the attached picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few issues here:

- syntax errors mixing `i` and `I`
- not saving the corrected name to FIRST_NAME
- unnecessary 2nd while loop in `letter_validity_check`

Here's a working solution that corrects these issues:

```
INVALID_CHARACTERS = r"!#$%&'()*+,-.:;<=>?@[]^_`{|}~\/" + '"'
INVALID_NUMBERS = "1234567890"
INVALID_LETTERS = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"


def letter_validity_check(name, msg):
    """Function checks entered answers against a list of invalid characters and invalid numbers"""

    while (
        len(name) == 0
        or any(c in INVALID_CHARACTERS for c in name)
        or any(c in INVALID_NUMBERS for c in name)
    ):
        name = input(
            "First name can not be blank, contain special characters, or numbers. Try again. \n"
            + msg
        )

    return name

    
FIRST_NAME = ""

while len(FIRST_NAME) == 0:
    MESSAGE = "What is your first name?: "
    FIRST_NAME = input(MESSAGE)
    FIRST_NAME = letter_validity_check(FIRST_NAME, MESSAGE)

print("Your first name is", FIRST_NAME)
```

A simpler version might be:

```
MESSAGE = "What is your first name? "
first_name = input(MESSAGE)

while not first_name.isalpha():
    print("First names may only contain alphabetic characters. Please try again.")
    first_name = input(MESSAGE)

print("Your first name is", first_name)
```

Comment: Hey, so the syntax was a weird copy-over issue.

However for the rest it is responding the same and is passing the entry BEFORE the correct entry ie. "h3llo" is prompting the re-type ( Yay ) but then when I type "hello" the return value is still "h3llo". I copy and pasted your while loop section.

Is this because the while loop is iterating on failure so there for according to my attached flow chart... The input isn't actually getting stored? Sorry guys, I wanna love coding but she's playing hard to get

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. Your posted code doesn't actually run because it has multiple syntax errors (not just indentation errors). I'm therefore assuming that the code you are running is different to what you've posted and because I can't see that code, I can't really comment on it. Were you able to successfully run the code I posted (either variant)? It's not difficult to trace what this code is doing. You can  work it out by reading the code. If that's problematic, then you can use a debugger to step through it.

Comment: Thank you @jarmod the second solution is way simpler. I think it's the while loop logic and I do not know how to work that out just yet. I think the logic of "do something" on failed input wasn't causing the latest input to be recorded properly. Idk, but that simplified version is god sent